# Visual Studio 2008 - Why do my windows keep rearranging themselves?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Every so often (at least a couple of times a day), my VS2008 windows are rearranging themselves.

Team/Solution/Server Explorer - They jump from the right sidebar down to the bottom, or suddenly become free-floating.

Same with Errors/Pending Changes/etc. free-floating or suddenly gone, as if they've been closed.

It is very strange behaviour. Has anyone else experienced it? Am I doing something silly that would account for this?

Comment: Any funny software running in the background that could be responsible for this?

Comment: Thomas - nothing too fruity. SQLMgr, Outlook, IE, Skype, Antivirus

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I have multiple instances of Visual Studio open at once and make a change. It seems the settings are stored when VS closes, so the last instance to close saves its settings over the others...

Answer (score 0):

Does that for me too, generally on multi-monitor systems. See if it does the same thing with your add-ons disabled, and consider switching which of your monitors is Primary.

Also, keep track of whether you last closed VS cleanly or ended the task because it was frozen again.

Comment: OK VS was acting up again so i restarted, cleanly i thought. Firing back up all my windows were gone, except the "Object Test Bench" which i never have open, and datasources. Three of the open file tabs now have no text and appear as small points in the tab bar. time for a reinstall i think :p

Answer (score 0):

Ditto - this randomly happens to me on my dual monitor setup as well. I hope someone has the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when opening new solutions?
The .suo file contains user settings which I believe includes window locations.

For this reason, they shouldn't be checked into source control, as they can override other's settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this too. My current project is a web service, and both the client test program and the service projects are both part of the same sln. So, to test, I have the sln open in two VS2008 instances. I always figured this was why it was happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

I get this all the time.  As far as I know, there isn't a "fix" for it.  Your best bet is to export your desired settings and then import them if things are screwed up.